# Jack post for sagging garage roof?

Tags: roof, support

Is the placement of this jack post okay to support sagging garage roof? What would a permanent solution look like?

[image]

[image: view from opposite side]

[image: close up view from opposite side showing upper portion of roof]

Comment: That looks like a double top plate carrying rafters. Was a load bearing wall removed at that location? Are those 4 ft spans or 6 ft spans on either side of the screw jack? Is there another roof above for carrying snow, roofers, etc.? Does this hypothetical roof have a load path that avoids loading the double top plate? You haven't provided sufficient information to learn the loading.

Comment: Above the door in the background, do I see an old gable end with a wall built on top of it? Are there any studs spanning from ground up to the roof level out there? Or are there breaks in old framing where roofs/ceilings/etc. used to interrupt the studs?

Comment: Can you give us a reverse angle showing what it looks like above the jack post from the window?

Comment: Looks like an addition built out of the side of a garage with the load bearing wall removed. You will need a beefy beam with proper foundations to support that weight safely.

Comment: I have added a couple photos for more context.

Comment: Do you have a substantial beam up along the ridge of the old roof? If there's a substantial ridge beam and posts carrying its load down to the ground, then your rafters are potentially okay without rafter ties. It looks, however, like you probably need a rafter tie or two in that square opening. If the square opening is important, then there exist other work arounds like collar ties or that substantial ridge beam.

Comment: For sizing the header, there is a table in the IRC that you can hack if you have a strong understanding of the concept of "tributary area." See https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction/IRC2021P2-Pt03-Ch06-SecR602.7.

Comment: If you're in an area with significant snow over the winter, then consider adding another post or two and a rafter tie or two while you get this figured out.

Comment: I deleted my answer because the additional photos show I was seeing it incorrectly.  Is that sagging beam supporting the intersection of two perpendicular gable roofs?   I think @popham has good suggestions.

Comment: It looks like the roofs were built on top of each other, and not only was the wall removed, almost all of the joists are gone too.  It's amazing that thing is still standing.

Comment: I totally get the DIY, I don't want to pay for a professional assessment thing. (Who wants to pay for services when you can get the answers for free on the internet?) However, I'd really suggest that a professional structural engineer would be the way to go to make sure your roof doesn't collapse. At a minimum, it would destroy this part of the structure, possibly vehicles, tools, etc stored inside, and worst kill someone who might be inside. Even if it's just the building collapse, the engineer's fee is still cheaper than rebuilding...

Comment: Thanks, this is a temporary solution until spring. I have a couple contractors look at it but they are busy. So, I am hoping to have something in place for a few months (there will be snow in the winter) to prevent a collapse. Yes, a load bearing wall was removed when an addition was built at the side of the garage. Is a single jack post like in the photo sufficient?

Comment: What's your snow load? If you don't know, then what region are you in? What is the old building's width perpendicular to the ridge? How wide is the addition measured from the face of the old building out to the wall with the exterior door? What's the pitch of the old roof (specifically its rafters)?

Comment: Do you have any idea of the USCS classification of your soil? Can you at least exclude the possibility of it belonging to the subset of cohesive and/or clayey soils?

Comment: And what is the opening's width?

Comment: Soil is clayey. The portion of the load bearing wall removed is about two bicycles width.

Comment: @Racoon, expand the question with the additional information, and bicycle lengths are an inappropriate metric.

Answer (score 1):

Any post must be supported itself. It seems to be resting on a rough concrete slab, which isn't adequate as a long-term solution unless there's a footing underneath. A slab isn't necessarily a foundation.

I'm still confused about what this is. I'm not sure how a "garage" is open to what looks like a living space.

Anyway, you have two options:

- A properly sized beam, properly supported all the way to footings
- A wall, properly sheathed or blocked and supported all the way to footings

Without knowing more about what's above and below that's about as specific as I can be. It doesn't look like a complicated thing, but some things need to be verified, as described.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consult with a professional engineer. There seem to be random structural problems in the background of your photos, where you would greatly benefit from a trained eye snooping around your place.

I need building dimensions and snow load for sizing headers and a work around for missing rafter ties (a horizontally oriented beam size and connection requirements for the rafter ties at the sides of your ceiling opening). Soil information for sizing proper footings would be nice.

Seeing the top of that gable end out at the exterior door's wall relieves some of my anxiety about that wall from your earlier post. If there are diagonal wall plates out there that interrupt the gable end studs, however, then the ridge beam connection is of critical importance. Usually your roof sheathing would brace that wall, but instead the diagonal wall plates along the upper hinge brace your wall. The ridge beam would be the only thing restraining the diagonal wall plates where they end at center, making the ridge beam's strength and connection strength of critical importance.

The additional flat hinge line in that wall is a probable problem. Without ties or a ceiling diaphragm to brace that hinge, wind or earthquake loads could be a problem. To achieve that architectural feature, your studs should have spanned uninterrupted from ground to roof level. With the hinge at that position, the bending strength of your wall plates carry loads horizontally to the side walls. They probably don't have adequate strength for transferring these loads. That little stub of floor out there could be helpful with proper detailing. That solution bothers me because I can easily imagine a future remodeler tearing out that stub of floor.

The load bearing opening details in that wall with the exterior door irritate me. Looking at the two walls popping out to join with that wall, the upper windows appear to leave little room for load bearing studs. The arrangement defies conventional framing. If I was on site, I would be sniffing around to verify the exact detailing of the roof and headers above those upper windows.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I admit there are quite a few technical terms which I do not understand. I bought this house a few months ago and the inspector noted structural issue with the garage (i.e. load bearing wall removed), which caused the garage to sag/lean one way. It's been like this for a few years presumably. My biggest concern is that it may collapse due to snow (possible to get a foot of snow which doesn't thaw until spring). The inspector suggested jack post as an interim solution. Thoughts?

Comment: @Racoon, if you're looking to limp through the winter, then you would want temporary posts and temporary rafter ties. Think of the ridge beam as a hinge between the rafters, where roof loading pushes the hinge down and tries to push the walls outward. The ceiling framing fights this outward load against pushing the walls by "tying" the rafters. Your missing chunk of ceiling has broken this mechanism in the neighborhood of your missing wall.

Comment: @Racoon, a single post seems inadequate to my intuition, but if it has survived a few winters like that, then maybe it will be okay.  Give me the dimensions that I asked for and your snow load or county, then I can detail the opening.